# Tableau and Simplex Method - No Calculator

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

A non-profit offers crafts complimentary gift packages for its donors. The non-profit costs for each package are \$4  for  the Bronze level package, \$7 for the Silver level package, and \$9 for the Gold level package. They have to use at least 45 coffee mugs in the packages they produce.

Each Bronze package contains 2 coffee mugs, each Silver package contains 3 coffee mugs, and each Gold package contains 4 coffee mugs. In addition, they have to use at least 40 pens.

Each Bronze package has 1 pen, each Silver package has 5 pens, and each Gold package has 2 pens. How many of each package should be made to minimize their cost? What is the minimum cost?

I'm thinking Tableau method, and got stuck in reducing the matrix

[image]

Comment: are we allowed fractional packages?

Comment: Nope - only integers

Answer (score 1):

When encountering a pivot element (column P3 in the case shown) that will not only make no progress but will not even change the tableau, you must reject it and use a different column.  In this case, the column to use for the next step needs to be P1, even though it is only the third most greedy choice.

The naive simplex method occasionally (but very rarely on real problems) gets stuck in even worse ways, including cycling through updates that change the tableau but do not improve the objective function.  Serious LP codes take steps to deal with these cases.

Your real problem, though, is that when you solve the continuous LP problem, you will probably end up at a non-integer solution.  (Though if this is a homework problem, assumedly it was chosen such that the solution arrived at is integers.) There is no guarantee that the best integer-only solution is near the solution you will reach, unless the latter is already all integers.

Answer (score 0):

First some variables have to defined.

$x: \text{Amount of Bronze level packages}$

$y: \text{Amount of Silver level packages}$

$z: \text{Amount of Gold level packages}$

coffe muggs constraint:

$2x+3y+4z\geq 45$

Pens constraint:

$1x+5y+2y\geq 40$

Objective function:

$\texttt{min } \ \ f=4x+7y+9z$

Integer  constraint

$x,y,z\in \mathbb Z_0^+$

For both constraints we need a slack variable and an aritificial variable each. Thus the initial table is

$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline &x &y&z&s_1&s_2&a_1&a_2& RHS  \\ \hline a_1&2&3&4&-1&0&1&0&45  \\ \hline a_2& 1&\color{blue}{5}&2&0&-1&0&1&40 \\ \hline  f&4&7&9&0&0&0&0&0 \\ \hline w&3&\color{red}{8}&6&-1&-1&0&0&85 \\ \hline \end{array}$

**Phase 0** is finished, $s_1,s_2$ are slack variables and $a_1,a_2$ are artifitial variables. $w=-a_1-a_2$. This the "second" objective function for calculating an basic feasible solution (bfs).

$-a_1=+2x+3y+4z-s_1$ and $-a_2=1x+5y+2z-s_2$

And **Phase 1** begins. The pivot column is $y$ because $\color{red}{8}$ is the largest number in row w. Now we have to choose the the pivot row. $min\left(\frac{45}3,\frac{40}{5} \right)=min(15,8)=8$. Thus the pivot row is $a_2$ and as a consequence the pivot element is $\color{blue}{5}$.

I leave it to you to finish Phase 1 and Phase 2, if neccessary. At the end of Phase 1 the RHS of $w$ has to be zero. If this not the case the problem is not feasible. Hopefully the solution will be an integer solution. If you have any question, feel free to ask.

**Calculation of a new element**

(no element of a pivot column or pivot row)

Let $a_{ij}, i\neq m,j\neq n$ be the element which has to be re-calculated, where $i$ is the number of the row and $j$ the number of the column. And $a_{mn}$ is the pivot element. Then the new value of $a_{ij}$ is

$a^*_{ij}=a_{ij}- \large{\frac{a_{mj}\cdot a_{in}}{a_{mn}}}$

$\Large{\texttt{Numerical example}}:$

$a_{ij}=a_{13}=4$ and $a_{mn}=a_{22}=5$. Thus

$a^*_{13}=a_{13}- \large{\frac{a_{23}\cdot a_{12}}{a_{22}}}$

$a^*_{13}=4- \large{\frac{2\cdot 3}{5}}$

$a^*_{13}=\frac{20}{5}-\frac{6}{5}=\frac{14}{5}$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42756/discussion-on-answer-by-callculus-tableau-and-simplex-method-no-calculator).