# LPP vs Convex optimisation

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming

I am studying for my statistics exam and we have Linear Programming,Simplex and graphical method, Duality Programming and Integer Programming. I have a great interest in Convex optimisation and wanted to know if any of this knowledge would help me to understand that better. In that case I would go through this more throughly as right now it just seems we need to remember the simplex and dual procedures without much theoretical understanding

Comment: This is a very general question. I would recommend you focus your question on one subject, graphical method for instance.

Comment: I mean simplex method mostly.

Comment: It is still a broad question. To start you can read [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1863741/144421).

Comment: This is hard to answer. I think convex analysis is a fascinating subject and of broad use, but, except for a few facts, and assuming you have little time available, I would stick with understanding the simplex method or now.

Comment: I don't understand people's difficulty in answering this very simple question. Let me reframe my question: Is understanding of Simplex method used for LPP useful in the field of Convex Optimisation?

Comment: @RahulDeora simple answer: no it is not. For your future career it may be better to focus on modelling and using optimization tools (with, say, Python) than it is to study algorithms.